# Have Chinese regulators ordered TV stations not to broadcast crime or time travel shows?

Tags: television

In April a [bunch](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/culturenews/8452907/Chinese-censors-attack-frivolous-time-travel-dramas.html) of [news](http://boingboing.net/2011/04/08/chinese-censors-ban.html) [services](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/04/13/chinese-government-bans_n_848769.html) claimed that the Chinese government had banned shows displaying time travel.

In May came [this announcement on BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-13308162):

> China has ordered TV stations across
>   the country not to air any detective
>   shows, spy thrillers or dramas about
>   time-travel for the next three months.

Is their any truth behind the claim made in May that detective shows, spy thrillers or dramas about time-travel are off air for the next three months?

When the time travel claim first came out I investigated it. One of the original articles from April 8 in BoingBoing links to the [SARFT statement](http://www.sarft.gov.cn/articles/2011/03/31/20110331140820680073.html). As I read by comments of some Chinese students the SARFT doesn't mention anything of a ban and doesn't even specifically mention time travel. So it would appear that the media is making this up based upon spurious claims.

Here is a cut down version of what is being said in SARFT statement (translation mine and paraphrased):

> Recently the content has been good,
>   however we discovered certain programs
>   were displaying programs that were
>   creatively inaccurate. These include
>   stories about spirits, fairy tales,
>   reincarnation and superstitions... In
>   this I hope that creative departments
>   will... make efforts to carry on the
>   fine tradition of Chinese culture and
>   make efforts to improve the dramas
>   ideological and artistic quality.

That's why I'm skeptical of later reports that now apparently include crime TV and soap operas as the original reports appear to be false and I can't see any report to back up the claim of 3 months.

Comment: sorry, but they've also banned the dissemination of any information as to whether they've banned those shows.

Comment: *"creatively inaccurate"* - what does that mean?